# JS Проверка массива слов на анаграммы с помощью функции

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Необходимо написать функцию checkAnagram, которая будет проверять, являются ли перечисленные слова в массиве анаграммами.

Аргументом функции checkAnagram является массив строк, которые нужно проверить.

Возвращаемое значение — true/false в зависимости от того можно ли все слова массива составить из одних и тех же букв.

Comment: Например, отсортировать все буквы в каждом слове, и просто сравнить строки `===`, пробовали?) Выдать задание и ждать готового решения - не формат для этого сайта...

Comment: Ох, я только недавно начал изучать JS, а тут столкнулся с этой задачкой, что даже нет идей, как к ней подступиться. Спасибо за наводку, как это можно сделать :) Не могли бы вы еще подсказать пожалуйста, с помощью каких команд это можно провернуть?

Comment: `let str = "bcad"; alert( str.split("").sort().join("") ); // "abcd"` — split("") разбивает строку на массив из букв, sort() по умолчанию сортирует их в алфавитном порядке, join("") собирает отсортированный массив обратно в строку. ### Первое слово из массива можно отсортировать и хранить в переменной, как контрольное. Перебирая остальные слова начиная со второго, сортировать их буквы и сравнивать получаемые слова с первым контрольным.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, что-то намутил так сказать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш вариант, немного подправленный (дополнительная переменная была не нужна):

```js
console.log(checkAnagram(["aabbcc", "ababcc", "abcabc"])); // true
console.log(checkAnagram(["aabbcc", "ababcF", "abcabc"])); // false

function checkAnagram(arr) {
  if (!arr || arr.length <= 1) return false;
  // Нет массива, или её длина 0 или 1, сразу на выход.
  
  let first_word = arr[0].split("").sort().join("");
  
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // от i = 1, не 0
    if (arr[i].split("").sort().join("") != first_word) {
      // Если вдруг [i]-тый элемент оказался не равным, можно не продолжать цикл
      return false;
      // Прямо отсюда выйти из функции, вернув false.      
    }
  }
  
  return true;
  // Цикл добежал и не прервался, значит все слова оказались равны
}
```

Можно еще взять и посчитать количество букв:

```js
console.log(checkAnagram(["aabbcc", "ababcc", "abcabc"])); // true
console.log(checkAnagram(["aabbcc", "ababcF", "abcabc"])); // false

function checkAnagram(arr) {
  if (!arr || arr.length <= 1) return false;
  
  let wordSize = arr[0].length;
  let wordLetters = countLetters(arr[0]);
  
  console.log( wordLetters ); 
  
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length != wordSize) return false; // Ширина не равна - до свидания
    
    let currLetters = countLetters(arr[i]);
    
    for (let letter in wordLetters) { // бежит по буквам эталонного слова
      if (wordLetters[letter] != currLetters[letter]) return false;
      // Все буквы, что были там, должны быть и в currLetters, в том же кол-ве.
    }
  }
  
  return true;
  
  /***/
  function countLetters(str) {
    let dictionary = {};
    
    for (let letter of str) {
      dictionary[letter] = (dictionary[letter] || 0) + 1;
      // dictionary[letter] — undefined? (буква не встречалась || возьмется 0) + 1
    }
    
    return dictionary;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вроде работает, но если это полотно возможно оптимизировать, не откажусь от советов :D

```
    function checkAnagram(anagramArray) {
        let total = 0;
        if (anagramArray == 0 || anagramArray.length == 1)
            total = false;
        else{
            for (let i = 0; i < anagramArray.length; i++) {
                let firstWord = anagramArray[0].split("").sort().join("");
                if (anagramArray[i].split("").sort().join("") == firstWord) {
                total = true;
                } else
                total = false;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

можно вот такой вариант:

```
const is_correct = arr.filter(obj => obj.split('').sort().join('').localeCompare(arr[0].split('').sort().join('')) === 0).length === arr.length;
```

Comment: Короткий и одновременно сложный для меня) И если поставить условие, что одно слово не может быть анаграммой, то функция должна возвращать false, а не true. Но спасибо за вариант

Comment: общий смысл алгоритма - для каждого элемента проверяем, является ли он анаграммой (состоит из тех же символов), что и первый элемент. а более подробно: 1) мы в массиве `arr` оставляем только те элементы, которые являются анаграммами первого элемента (для этого используем метод `filter` - он оставляет только элементы удовлетворяющие условию 2) для определения анаграммности каждую строку мы а) раскладываем в массив символов через метод `split('')` б) сортируем массив через метод `sort` (чтобы все строки были одинакового формата) в) собираем массив в строку через `join` и сравниваем строки